# How can I make this custom range function work with negative steps?

Tags: python, function, range

This is what I have so far. It works properly with the other 3 arguments, but once I change the step to a negative number it doesn't return the expected output. I've added the built-in range function at the end to have as a reference.

```
def myRange(start, stop = None, step = None):
    if(step == None and stop== None ):
        stop = start
        start = 0
        step = 1
    elif(step == None):
        step = 1
    res = []
    if (step < 0):
        while stop < start:
            res.append(start)
            start += step
   

    else:
        while start < stop:
            res.append(start)
            start += step
        return res

def main():
    print(myRange(5, 20))
    print(myRange(5, 100, 5))
    print(myRange(20, 10, -1))
    print(list(range(20, 10, -1)))
    print(myRange(100, 500, 50))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The problem is that you're still checking for `stop < start`. Iteration works when `start` begins less than and is increased toward `stop`, but not when `start` begins more than and is decreased toward `stop`. I'm sure you can figure out what condition to check instead and how to make that decision based on `start` and `stop`.

Comment: Hi, I've answered your question, and it works. Do you mind to take a look at it?

Comment: Hi Juan, Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a little mistake, you should unindent the `return res`.
Like this

```py
else:
     while start < stop:
         res.append(start)
         start += step
return res
```

Comment: I updated the code